# Binding to a ReactiveUI Service from a View

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am using RxUI 7 and struggling to bind a RxUI property from a constant service (registered with Splat) that derives from ReactiveObject to my Xamarin Forms View.

I have a service registered as follows when the App initialises:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new CurrentAudioService(), typeof(ICurrentAudioService));
```

I then have CurrentAudioService implemented as follows:

```
public class CurrentAudioService : ReactiveObject, ICurrentAudioService
{
    private bool _isPlaying;

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return _isPlaying; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isPlaying, value); }
    }
}
```

ICurrentAudioService defines IsPlaying correctly.

In my view I have tried the following:

```
private readonly ICurrentAudioService _currentAudioService;

public PlayerView() : base()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Resolve the view
    _currentAudioService = _currentAudioService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<ICurrentAudioService>();

    this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
    {
        this.OneWayBind(_currentAudioService, cas => cas.IsPlaying, c => c.Player.IsVisible)
            .DisposeWith(disposables);
    }
}
```

If I change the code within WhenActivated to:

```
_currentAudioService.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsPlaying)
    .Subscribe((isPlaying) =>
    {
        Player.IsVisible = isPlaying;
    })
    .DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Everything works as expected. Why does this fail when I try to bind to the service and is there any way to make this work?

To clarify, the reason why the currentAudioService is implemented as a service rather than a view model is because the currentAudioService will be shared amongst all views in the application (each of which will have their own controls that interact with the currentAudioService).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that using `Bind` relies on the `ViewModel` property of the View and can only bind to Properties inside that VM as I understand it.

IMHO `WhenAnyValue` is the correct approach because you want to observe a Value that is outside the ViewModel.

Two other possibilties come to mind:

1. Put the `WhenAnyValue`in you ViewModel together with a `toProperty` and then Bind your Views Control to that property in your ViewModel
2. Expose the state change in your service not as bool but as IObservable the you can subscribe to that Observable in your View.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your approach. Instead of using a service, if you have several ViewModels with the same functionality, just create a ViewModelBase like the following one:

```
public class PlayerBaseViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
   private bool _isPlaying;
   public bool IsPlaying
   {
      get { return _isPlaying; }
      set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isPlaying, value); }
   }
}
```

Then you can simple inherit from it in the ViewModels that share the same functionality. Also don't forget that in ReactiveUI you need to implement the interface `IViewFor<YourViewModel>` in your Views in order to associate the ViewModel with the corresponding View.

If you are using the Nuget package reactiveui-xamforms, instead of implementing the `IViewFor<YourViewModel>` your views can inherit from `ReactiveContentPage<SearchViewModel>` which is implementing the `IViewFor` for you.

Hope this help.

Regards

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to achieve. I have several pages which all have a player control (with its own viewmodel), but a central service that plays audio (so that it runs across each of the pages and doesn't stop when you navigate between pages). I'm trying to bind a the visibility of the playercontrol based on a property of the service (e.g. IsPlaying). Inheriting from a ViewModelBase (which I do anyway) wouldn't help here, because it still wouldn't know when the audio service properties update.